# XMLRunner - "unicode object has no attribute 'write'" when building

Tags: python, unit-testing, unicode, python-unittest, pybuilder

I have a project being built with Pybuilder.  I cloned it onto a new computer, and when I ran `pyb`, my unit tests complained that there was no module named `xmlrunner`.  So after I did `pip install xmlrunner`, I get a build error from Pybuilder that:

`'unicode' object has no attribute 'write'`.

If I remove my unit tests from the unittest search path, the build completes successfully.  When I run the unit tests directly, they complete successfully.  So I'm thinking that somehow XMLRunner is failing.  Pip installed XMLRunner version 1.7.7.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have got this working by doing the following:

First I got the same error as you:

> BUILD FAILED - 'unicode' object has no attribute 'write'

Then I uninstalled `xmlrunner` & `unittest-xml-reporting` using `pip`

Then I used `pyb install_dependencies` which reinstalls `unittest-xml-reporting`

Then my unit tests start running again when I use `pyb`:

> There were 1 error(s) and 0 failure(s) in unit tests

This is my current `pip list` output:

> pip (7.1.2)
>
> PyBuilder (0.11.1)
>
> setuptools (18.2)
>
> six (1.9.0)
>
> tblib (1.1.0)
>
> unittest-xml-reporting (1.12.0)
>
> wheel (0.24.0)

If you are using virtualenv, you can also get this error when you have **pybuilder installed outside of your virtualenv environment**:

> For example, your virtualenv does not have `pybuilder` installed, but you can still run `pyb` from command line. It is this `pybuilder` that needs to be removed as well (I am on OSX so it was the default python that came with it)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved for me when I downgraded PyBuilder to 0.10.63 from 0.11.0.  In their release notes (here: http://pybuilder.github.io/releasenotes/) for that 0.10.63, they mention "Fixed a regression introduced in 0.10.62 where the unit test reports generated by the python.unittest plugin would always be empty."

For some reason this fixed it completely for me.